# How to reset/clear a Formik FieldArray that is conditionally rendered?

Tags: reactjs, select, formik

Using Formik, I am conditionally rendering via a select list value, a FieldArray that has two fields, i.e. name and age.

My question is, assuming that I have rendered this FieldArray relating to name and age and have created 5 rows of info but I then decide to change the select list value to another value that now hides this FieldArray. In doing so, how can I clear/reset this FieldArray back to null?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to do this based on the structure of your form component.

Here is one way which uses `setFieldValue` function exported by Formik to explicitly set a value to a field.

```
const FormComp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik>
        {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
          <Form>
            <select
              onChange={(e) => {
                const {value} = e.target;
                let shouldResetFieldArray = value !== 'showFieldArray'; // replace with actual condition
                if (shouldResetFieldArray) {
                  setFieldValue("fieldArrayKey", []); // reset fieldArrayKey to empty array [];
                }
              }}
            ></select>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Just wondering how I would be able to call `setFieldValue("fieldArrayKey", []);` as part of a ternary operator, i.e. `(a==3) ? <Show /> : setFieldValue("fieldArrayKey", []);` ?

Comment: @tonyfat It will be good if you could update the question with relevant code.

Comment: I will actually raise a new SO question regarding this.

Comment: Created a new SO question regarding this over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67100285/how-to-call-a-function-component-as-part-of-a-ternary-operation